# Does the CSR(Certificate signing request) file used for creating developer or distribution certificate and push certificate has to be same?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

So when creating a new push certificate can I use a new CSR file.Does the CSR file used for creating developer or distribution certificate and push certificate has to be same?
Will push notifications work if they are different?

Comment: No, you can use different ones

Comment: So they doesn't have to be same? @allenh

Comment: Correct. CSRs are for getting new certificates. Certificates are used to establish trust. The certificates used for APNS establish trust independently of those used for app signing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's certificate process is similar to other certificate systems. When you make the CSR your own system actually generates a public and private key pair. The CSR contains the public key. Apple uses that public key to make a certificate. A certificate is more or less a way of publishing a public key along with some related information about that key, and of verifying that the issuing entity (Apple in this case) represents that this information is valid.

Since each certificate has their own public-private key pair, then your push certificate and developer and distribution certificates can all use different CSRs. Each certificate is used to authenticate and secure that particular item.

Your development or distribution profile is used to connect the application ID (aka Bundle ID in some documentation) with your developer or distribution certificates. Your APNS push certificate is made with your application ID, so that ties it to your app in that way.

So it's the application ID that connects these things together in the Apple system.

In short you can use the same or different CSR as you wish. (Although security people would prefer you use a different CSR for each one.)